# Model=QSqlTAbleModel(self) que no funciona

Tags: python-3.x

Llevo con esta cuestión varios días porque lo escribo como está en el ejemplo de la aplicación y como veo en otros sitios, pero no me funciona en absoluto.

En importaciones tengo

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
```

En main.py

```
db=QSqlDtaBase.addDataBae("QSQLIT")

db.setDataBaseName("telefonos.db")
```

he comprobado que se ha establecido conexión con la DB y con la tabla "guia_telefonos" y se me ha presentado la tabla en

```
self.buscarModel=QSqlQueryModel(self)
```

(sin este self también funciona OK)

```
self.buscarModel.setQuery("select * from guia_telefonica")

self.tableView_buscar.setModel(self.buscarModel).
```

(Hay además un lineEdit)

Hasta aquí lo que funciona; lo que no funciona es

```
self.eliminarModel=QSqlTableMode(self)
```

(lo he probado con y sin este self)

```
self.eliminarModel.setTable("guia_telefonos")

self.eliminarModel.select()

self.eliminar_tableView.setEditTriggers(QTableView.NoEditTriggers)

self.eliminar_tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableview.SelectRows)

self.eliminar_TableView.setModel(self.eliminarModel)

self.eliminar_Tableview.clicked.connect(self.onEliminar_tableview_clicked)
```

He revisado la GUI y está bien, pero ejecuto y Añadir, me funciona bien, Buscar, también pero Eliminar, no me da error, simplemente no aparece ni la tabla ni su contenido. No me da ninhún error, simplemente no me aparece la tabla ni vacía ni llena. Al autor de la aplicación le funciona con lo mismo, pero a mí, nada de nada. ¿Qué podría ser?

Answer (score 0):

Uff, solucionado. Me da vergüenza la solución, pero de los nuevos, ya se sabe. Tenía dos nombres diferentes en el código para una misma tabla. Los he puesto como se debe y funciona. Aunque no es para presumir, también me es muy útil descubrir mis errores, me obliga a repasar bien repasado el código.